# Add empty inputs to an array with the value of 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

As a project I am building a "barebones" budgeting web-app. I have a form with a number of inputs to fill out income sources and amounts.

```
<form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeSrc1" placeholder="Enter Source" name="incomeSrc">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeSrc2" placeholder="Enter Source" name="incomeSrc">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeSrc3" placeholder="Enter Source" name="incomeSrc">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeSrc4" placeholder="Enter Source" name="incomeSrc">
      </div>
    </form>
```

And

```
<form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount1" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="incAmount">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount2" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="incAmount">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount3" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="incAmount">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount4" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="incAmount">
      </div>
    </form>
```

I tried to put all the inputs into a array **amountArr** so that I could add them together and determine the largest source of income.

This was my latest attempt :

```
var incAmount = document.getElementsByName("incAmount");
var amountArr = [];
//Income input function 
for (var index = 0; index < incAmount.length; index++) {
    incAmount[index].addEventListener("input", add3);
    function add3() {
        for (var i = 0; i < incAmount.length; i++) {
             amountArr[i] = parseFloat(incAmount[i].value);
            if (incAmount[i].value === NaN) {
                amountArr[i] = 0;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

The goal is that if an input wasn't filled then its value in the array will be 0. However all my attempts either threw errors like -

> incAmount[i].value is undefined

or the array was filled with NaN's.

I also tried

```
if (amountArr[i].value !== NaN)
```

and

```
if (isNaN(amountArr[i]))
```

None of them returned true (executed the ensuing code)

Why doesn't amountArr or an empty incAmount reurn true when compared to NaN/null/undefined?

Comment: Where is `incAmount` defined?

Comment: You could just prefill it with 0 to avoid checking that. Then if it is not NaN, then insert the value.

Comment: var incAmount = document.getElementsByName("incAmount");

Comment: right above the function

Comment: @AnthonyVoelker I tried something similar. IF incAmount[i].value !== NaN then insert value, ELSE = 0. That also didn't work...

Comment: This question was fully researched and imho quite useful. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.

```
for (var i = 0; i < incAmount.length; i++) {
         amountArr[i] = parseFloat(incAmount[i].value) || 0;
```

The array amountArr will show 0's for all empty inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseFloat` in the condition to convert the empty value to `NaN` before comparison.

-Or you should use the `amountArr[i]` in the condition to check if that is `NaN`.

Also, you should use `isNaN` function to check for `NaN` value.

```
if (isNaN(amountArr[i])) {
   amountArr[i] = 0;
```

Comment: I tried using parseFloat in a previous attempt and it throws a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.add3

Comment: Check the place where you populate `incAmount` array. Make sure you put the value and it is effected.

Comment: The value of incAmount is a node list, as I mentioned above

Comment: Edit your question to include the parts which set `incAmount ` array